# Javascript Prompt dialog customize input

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I want to have a field like this in the prompt-dialog in javascript, so the user can quickly select a date

That input field should look like this

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: the prompt dialog box can't be modified. However, you may create the prompt dialog yourself and use an input with type `date` ; note that some browsers are not compliant with new html5 input kinds.

Comment: The appearance of the `datepicker` ui element will vary across different browsers. `In the Prompt dialog` suggests in some sort of popup? You cannot directly include HTML elements in any native modal dialog in javascript - you would need to build your own modal or use jQuery or other

Comment: No; You can't set the input-type of a js-prompt-Dialog. If you wish, you can add a custom Dialog and put an Input date element there (like jquery-ui Dialog https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can do very customized things with **[Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)**.

Example with date input:

```
const {
  value: formValue
} = await Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select a date',
  html: '<input type="date" id="swal-input" class="swal2-input">',
  focusConfirm: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  preConfirm: () => {
    return document.getElementById('swal-input').value;
  }
})
```

The result of running this will be a popup in the center of the screen with a date input box:

[image]

[image]

The selected date will be stored in the variable called `formValue`.

#### [Installation instructions](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download)

To get started quickly, you can include this script at the beginning of the HTML:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs I think you can use jQuery datepicker
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

if you want the calendar to be inline you can do that too
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

The source code is at the bottom of the pages.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However, i would need it in a prompt-input dialog from javascript